# SwiftUI - How to get correct RGB value from theme aware named color?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

The following is a code example from widget extension.

By using `.environment(\.colorScheme, ...)`, I am able to update view with correct theme aware named color.

However, I am not able to retrieve the correct RGB value, from the theme aware named color.

```
private func getColorScheme() -> ColorScheme {
    if ... {
        return ColorScheme.dark
    } else {
        return ColorScheme.light
    }
}

@ViewBuilder
func contentView() -> some View {

    // Light/ dark theme aware
    let color = SwiftUI.Color("yellowNoteColor")

    calculate(color)
    
    HStack {
        ...
    }
    .background(color)
    .environment(\.colorScheme, getColorScheme())
}

func calculate(_ color: SwiftUI.Color) {
    var a: CGFloat = 0.0
    var r: CGFloat = 0.0
    var g: CGFloat = 0.0
    var b: CGFloat = 0.0

    let uiColor = UIColor(self)
    uiColor.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)

    // !!! Always get the light theme color value !!!
}
```

Inside `calculate` function, the retrieved value is always in the light theme color value.

My guess is, `caculate` function is executed before `.environment(\.colorScheme, getColorScheme())`, that's why we are getting light theme color value always.

May I know, how to get correct RGB value from theme aware named color?

---

### Side note:

In main app, we can change the main app theme using `overrideUserInterfaceStyle`, then retrieve correct RGB, based on selected main app theme.

But, I am not sure how can we do so in `WidgetKit`.

Comment: It's a dynamic color.

Comment: @matt yes. that is dynamic color. In main app, we can change the main app theme using `overrideUserInterfaceStyle`, then retrieve correct RGB, based on selected main app theme. But, I am not sure how can we do so in widgetkit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `resolvedColor` method on `UIColor` directly to get proper values. So you could pass the color name to your calculate method instead of passing `SwiftUI.Color` instance.

Since `UIColor` is available in `Widgets` as well it should give you correct RGB values.

**Why is it not working in your case?**

My guess is since `SwiftUI.Color` is a struct and you pass it in your `calculate` method, when the system changes its RGB values based on the given `ColorScheme` it creates a copy of the color instance. So your `calculate` method still has the old copy(With RGB values from the light color scheme) but the system has the correct copy(With RGB values from dark colour scheme)

```
@ViewBuilder
func contentView() -> some View {
    let name = "yellowNoteColor"
    let color = SwiftUI.Color(name)
    calculate(name)
    return VStack {
        Image(systemName: "globe")
            .imageScale(.large)
            .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
        Text(calculate(name))
    }
    .background(color)
    .environment(\.colorScheme, getColorScheme())

}

func calculate(_ name: String) -> String {
    var a: CGFloat = 0.0
    var r: CGFloat = 0.0
    var g: CGFloat = 0.0
    var b: CGFloat = 0.0

    if let uiColor = UIColor(named: name)?.resolvedColor(with: UITraitCollection(userInterfaceStyle: .dark)) {
        uiColor.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
        return "Red: \(r), Green: \(g), Blue: \(b), Alpha: \(a)"
    }
    return ""
}
```

[image: Xcode]
[image: Simulator]

Comment: Our widget is designed around `SwiftUI.Color`. Do you think it has something equivalent to `UIColor`'s resolveColor?

Comment: To be honest I checked but could not find anything. I saw you posted the same question on Apple developer forum as well, but no answer. So my guess is no

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I will then use this as a workaround, to create another set of `UIColor`, so that I can retrieve correct color value during computation.